Mi Maquina virtual no conecta a internet
Estoy trabajando en unos servidores, tengo de uno de apache2, el cual le agregue mi pagina, pero que pasa, que lo hice desde mi casa, con mi internet, agregue una ip estatica en al configuracion de netplan, cuando me conecto a otro internet la maquina deja de conectarse a internet, y no puede hacer ping con nada, ya probe de todo, pero sigo sin encontrar el problema.
Me sale destination host unreachable.
configuración de netplan:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.100/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]

Cabe aclarar, que antes funcionaba de cualquier internet, peor no se que cambio
Pobre la configuracion de netplan, y mire el virtual box pero nada.

Un diagrama mostrando cada máquina y router, con sus respectivas IP sería de garn utilidad.

Si estás usando el "modo bridge" recuerda que la IP del gateway (routes) de la VM tiene que corresponder con la IP de tu router. Si en tu casa esa IP es 192.168.1.1, con la config que pones va a conectar; pero si en "el otro internet" el GW del router es (por ejemplo) 192.168.3.1, entonces no va a conectar. En ese caso tendrías que cambiar también la IP de la máquina virtual a ese segmento de red, por ejemplo 192.168.3.100/24.
